# firebase console | add user by mobile number

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I was going through firebase console, in the users' tab I can add the users by EmailId and Password, But I am unable to add a user with the phone number.

My requirement is that I want to upfront add all the phone-numbers into firebase users database.

Comment: I think it is impossible to add users by phone number using the console because Firebase requires some extra authentication with phone numbers that is not necessary with emails. i.e. you have to authenticate the number on the device while you don't actually have to verify any email addresses.

Comment: Maybe with the user management commands of the CLI??? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#user_management_commands (I have never tried however)